# Which MA(q) to use for hourly data in Time Series decomposition?

Tags: r, arima, seasonality, trend

I am trying to do a Time Series decomposition manually (I don't wanna use one of those R packages that give you all already done). I have already removed the mean from my TS by dividing the TS by its mean, so now it's centered around 1.

I'd like to divide it by the Moving Average to remove the seasonality.
The fact is that I guess it has to be 24 lags, as it is 24 hours data. However, when I try to get a more precise estimation of the seasonality by using the following:

```
library(TSA)
p <- periodogram(hournorm$count)  #we look at the possible frequencies of seasonality
#now we try to figure out which they are
dd = data.frame(freq=p$freq, spec=p$spec)
order = dd[order(-dd$spec),]
top5 = head(order, 5)
# display the 5 highest "power" frequencies
 top5
# convert frequency to time periods
time <- 1/top5$f
time
```

I obtain that seasonality is around 21 hours.

So what should I use? Stick with 24h seasonality or use the obtained seasonality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a subject-matter explanation for why the seasonal cycle should be 21 rather than 24 hours?

- If yes, you could try using 21 as the seasonal frequency in further modelling. Perhaps this is some mechanical process that does not depend on the time of the day and has a seasonal period of 21 hours.
- If no, and furthermore, if there is a subject-matter explanation for why the cycle should be 24 hours, I would stick to a 24-hour cycle.

Also, is the signal at the 21-hour frequency much stronger than that of 24-hour frequency? You could include a plot in your post to show us the periodogram you have.

A side note: it is quite usual to remove the mean by subtracting the sample mean from the observations rather than by dividing them by it. But here it does not play any role anyway.

Comment: Also, I am not sure about dividing by MA to remove seasonality... I do not commonly encounter such a method in time series applications.